# how to read IDFA in .mobileConfig file in safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, safari

Since UDID is deprecated and our web app (also has a native version) was depending on UDID of the device to uniquely identify user in system. We switched to IDFA in native version but we cant figure out how to read IDFA using .mobileconfig in safari. Or any other way to read IDFA in safari ? any heads up will really be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody has any ideas ??